# How to get the Last Active Date of a Process?

Tags: c++, windows, atl, win32com

I have an assignment were in I have to print the last active date of the process using a COM In Proc Server in C++. I tried doing that with getProcessTimes() function, but that gives me an access violation error.

First of all, I want to know if there is anyother command that gives the last active date of the process..

Second what is the problem with the following code

```
FILETIME ftCreation, ftKernel, ftUser;
GetProcessTimes(hProcess, &ftCreation, &ftExit, &ftKernel, &ftUser);`
```

I tried memsetting and several other alternatives but nothing works...

Comment: Where have you got the `hProcess` from?

Comment: Also how is `ftExit` declared?

Comment: FILETIME ftCreation, ftKernel, ftUser , ftExit;

hProcess is just a handle to a process...

I am trying to obtain a handle to each and every process and then trying to get process times for that process..

Comment: are you actually trying to retrieve last date on which app was running? or specify more last active date...

Comment: Last time the process was loaded on to the memory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/getprocesstimes.aspx) that demonstrates how to use `GetProcessTimes`. It includes sample code. Another option is using [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) and the [WIN32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(VS.85).aspx) class, which also has this information. Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423(v=VS.85).aspx) of how you would use WMI.